# Is it possible to snap a prefab perpendicular to a surface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm trying to build a scene with a number of prefabs placed onto a tiny planet, think [something like this](http://img09.deviantart.net/62aa/i/2012/295/8/f/tiny_planet_001_by_oskarperez-d5hzneh.jpg). The problem I am facing is that while I can place prefabs on a sphere easily using Control+Shift, they are not rotated and thus appear at terrible rotations. I'm aiming for them to be placed perpendicularly.

Currently I am aware of three solutions:

1. Place the objects in the scene using Control+Shift then manually rotate them into position.
2. Place the objects in the scene like before, then add a snippet of code to each of their Update methods: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, transform.position - origin) * transform.rotation;`
3. Like option 2, run the code and find some way to save the world state to the scene, but [that is easier said than done](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/600288/how-do-i-save-instantiated-bundle-to-scene-.html). It seems like to much effort for something that should be trivial.

The first is tedious and hard to correctly align, the second is easy but renders your scene builder unrepresentative of your final game, and I have no idea where to start on the third. Is there a better way?

Comment: I have also tried Vertex Snapping, but it doesn't orient prefabs perpendicularly either.

Comment: It seems like there are two questions here: (1) how do you orient objects perpendicular to a surface, and (2) how can you achieve this in the editor to produce a saved scene where that has been done. Is that right? Is question 1 or 2 giving you more trouble?

Comment: You could try adding [ExecuteInEditMode] header to your class. That will make so your Update code will run in edit mode. The other way is creating an editor script but that is a bit more work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I decided to perform all of the orientation manually using Control+Shift. As Johan suggested you could write your own `[ExecuteInEditMode]` Editor scripts, and if the planet I was foresting was significantly bigger I would have looked into it.

Be aware that if you do venture down the scripting path that the object isn't floating and fully clips through the surface. Manual placement may be necessary after all.